# jquery mouseover causing flickering

Tags: jquery, mouseover

As to be viewed at: http://jsfiddle.net/pBt38/5/ I dont know how to stop the flickering of the div.message_options_slider, its a child element so isn't it supposed to keep the mouseover active?

Also, any suggestions need to have the .live() function as this will be applied to dynamic elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You got a float problem...but your CSS and that is so large, can you not simplify it?

Comment: no its part of a larger project, I just copied all of it to make sure I wouldnt miss any.

Comment: Well you've got a few problems, for one your hover over is actually being attached to one of the items it is supposed to be hovering over not to the body. Second is as Gho5t mentioned the positioning. In fact the JS fundamentally is flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this JS:

```
$(".network_block_item").on("mouseover", function(){
    //alert("here");
    var cord = $(this).position();

    $(this).find(".message_options_slider").css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: cord.top,
        left: 0,
        display: 'block'       
    });
});

$(".network_block_item").on("mouseout", function(){
    $(".message_options_slider").css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

And add the message_options_slider to every network row thing.

#### Edit

This code might actually be better, not sure:

```
$(".network_block_item").on("mouseenter", function(){
    //alert("here");
    var cord = $(this).position();

    $(this).find(".message_options_slider").css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: cord.top,
        left: 0,
        display: 'block'       
    });
});

$(".network_block_item,.message_options_slider").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".message_options_slider").css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

Comment: why do you use the .network_block_item twice on the mouseleave though?

Comment: Ok try that, now when you leave the hover over it will hide, I would give fiddle but I dont actually have a fiddle account :|

Answer (score 1):

the `message_options_slider` is a child of the 3rd div, so when you change its position to go on top of the currently hovered `div`, it triggers a 'mouseout' (notice how there is no flickering if you hover over the 3rd div).  You could have a `message_options_slider` in each div and change the CSS for that corresponding div, or you can insert it into the current div so it doesn't flicker

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here. If you want to just have one instance of the popup, you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pBt38/6/